# How can I recover files in an app bundle that were lost after an OS update?

Tags: recovery, data-recovery

I saved a file in an app's application content (right clicked the application file, and then clicked Show Package Contents) for security issues. However, during the upgrade to OS X Lion, I completely forgot it was there and subsequently the app was updated and the file is gone! It was the application Stickies, in case that's helpful. Does anyone know if there's any way I can recover it?

EDIT: No longer looking for a solution, files have been found using diskdrill.

Comment: Hi Simon - Welcome to the site - I think we need more details, as I am unsure what you mean in your first sentence.  Please can you edit with extra details to allow us to better help you.

Comment: Thanks. Apologies, I realised it was very vague after first posting! Is it now understandable?

Comment: @simonthumper I assume you don't have a backup you can refer to and that you've checked in the Stickies app for your file?

Comment: No, no back up I'm afraid... I only tend to back up my documents, and yes I've checked in the app :/ Currently trying some disk recovery programmes...

Comment: It's fine, got hold of it using diskdrill :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Since you solved your problem, could you please post your solution as an Answer? That way, future visitors will be able to see that the problem has been solved and see how you did it. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I tried answering, it says I cant for another 6 hours, because I have below 100 reputation points...

Comment: @simonthumper Then I await your answer to upvote it (as I'd never heard of diskdrill) and you'll be on your way to 100 rep.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to recover my file by downloading the free version of [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/mac-data-recovery.html).  I used the deep search options locate removed files on my Mac; you can view results by type of file, however names as far as I can see are not conserved, so you will have to preview each file one by one.  To actually recover the file you must upgrade to the Pro version of the software.